# Access product information in custom source model for "dynamic" product attribute

Tags: magento, models

I want to programmatically create a product attribute dropdown that shows all categories that the product is assigned to. With this, I would like to define a default category that can be used in the products 'canonical' tag url.

In order to do that I started creating a source model, and in this source model I want to access the product to dynamically create the dropdown options.

Is this possible? If so, how should I go about it? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: This is no magento standard functionality. I need to write a new source model in order to achieve this, which is why I believe this clearly is a programming related question. If I am mistaken, however, I can close it. I found the answer just now, so I'll answer it for future reference

Comment: There was nothing that I could see that specifically said that you wanted to code this. It could have been a request for an extension or a how-to guide for Magento. The question needs to specifically and clearly be about programming.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to a colleague of mine:

To create a product attribute which lists all categories of a product, I can load the product from the Magento registry via `Mage::registry('current_product)`. This leads to the following content in the `getAllOptions()` method:

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
    $categoryIds = Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryIds();

    $this->result[] = array(
        'value' => '-1',
        'label' => 'None'
    );

    foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
        $this->result[] = array(
            'label' => Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getName(),
            'value' => $categoryId
        );
    }
    return $this->result;
}
```